# Speed up partitioning ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have this query (SQL Server):

```sql
DECLARE @PageNum int = 1;
DECLARE @PageSize int = 2;
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Color ORDER BY Name) AS Row
  FROM Orders
) t1
WHERE Row BETWEEN ((@PageNum-1)*@PageSize+1) AND (@PageNum*@PageSize)
ORDER BY Color,Name
```

What this query does is it selects "pages" with 2 records for every `Color`. Meaning if the table contains:

| Id | Color | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Paper #1 |
| 2 | Red | Paper #2 |
| 3 | Red | Paper #3 |
| 4 | Green | Paper #4 |
| 5 | Green | Paper #5 |
| 6 | Green | Paper #6 |
| 7 | Green | Paper #7 |

Then the above query would result in:

| Id | Color | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | Paper #1 |
| 2 | Red | Paper #2 |
| 4 | Green | Paper #4 |
| 5 | Green | Paper #5 |

At page 1 and

| Id | Color | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Red | Paper #3 |
| 6 | Green | Paper #6 |
| 7 | Green | Paper #7 |

At page 2.

This works. However, in my real-world example, this query takes a very long time to execute--about 10 minutes in fact. I have a static table with over 800K records which *never* changes. Since this table never changes, I created an index for every column I would filter/sort by. This table also has a column `RowId`, which is practically just the row number, and it has a unique index.

The execution plan can be seen here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkeWfVCSY

What can I do to speed up this query?

Comment: Also looks like you are reinventing `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. As long as you are using 2012 or later you don’t need to do so. I’ve seen some very bad plans get better with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Comment: @DaleK I updated my question. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Mitch According to the execution plan, it doesn't seem like that's the issue. Even if I leave the WHERE clause out, nothing changes.

Comment: You need an index on `[OrderType] desc, [From] asc` or `[OrderType] asc, [From] DESC` to get rid of the sort operation.

Comment: have you tried `OFFSET/FETCH`? You may want to look at [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset), which is far more efficient than Rowset Pagination which you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first operation in your execution plan is a table scan, so I assume this is a heap table (otherwise we should see a clustered index scan) and the indexes you created are not being used.

Also, once this is a static table that never changes, according to the description, fragmentation should not be a problem.

I don't have SQL Server installed in this machine so I can't compare the execution plans before and after, but I believe that for your query, we may see some improvements with a clustered index, ordering the keys as Martin Smith suggests in his comment.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Order ON dbo.Order(OrderType ASC, From DESC)
```

Please let me know if this improves your query. If not, I can create a similar scenario to test during the day.